# How to avoid automatic evalf() on new sympy.functions?

Tags: python, function, sympy

I would like to create a function that remains unevaluated unless I explicitly demand it through `evalf()`. I tried this (following the example in http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/index.html)

```
In [1]: import sympy as sy

In [2]: class f(sy.Function):
   ...:     def _eval_evalf(self,prec):
   ...:         print "evalf"
   ...:         return sy.S(1)
   ...:     

In [3]: f(1)
Out[3]: f(1)

In [4]: f(1)+1
Out[4]: evalf
1 + f(1)
```

As can be seen, the function stays away from `_eval_evalf()` in  [3], but it goes through `_eval_evalf()` in [4], beating my purpose of defining a symbolic function in the first place. I also tried adding this

```
 @classmethod
 def _should_evalf(cls, arg):
     return -1
```

but it didn't solve the problem.

Is there a simple way (I'm not very familiar with classes) to prevent the function f going through `_eval_evalf()`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `_should_evalf` will prevent the function from automatically evaluating. The result of your `1 + f(1)` is `1 + f(1)`, not `2`.

`_eval_evalf` gets called in other places, when a function needs to know a numeric value for an expression. You can raise an exception or use `import traceback; traceback.print_stack()` to see where `_eval_evalf` is being called.

Comment: If you look at [4] you can see that "evalf" was printed, i.e., `_eval_evalf()` was called at some point, even though the final result `1+f(1)` would indicate that `_eval_evalf()` was not called.

Comment: @andres yes, as I indicated in my answer, evalf is sometimes called for other things. You can raise an exception to see exactly where. In this case, I think it is being called to help Add sort its arguments (this isn't something that IMHO should be done, but in any case, it is).